# How can I convert my Windows C program to run on a Linux system?

Tags: c, linux, windows, converters

I would like to convert the following program to run on a linux system for my school assignment. I am struggling very hard because the linux computer labs are shutdown due to covid. So, I coded my homework on my windows computer. I had access today and it did not run due to multiple errors. What can I do to convert my code to make it linux compatible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>






char ch;

#define NUMROWS 6
#define NUMCOLS 6
int i, j;

char str1[42] = {'S', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '\n', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '\n', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '\n', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '\n', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', 'G', '\n', '#', '#', '.','.','.','#','\n'};


main()
{


    
    
    char response[10];
    char response2[10];
    char yes;
    char no;
    char ready;
    char notready;
    
    printf("Do you want to play the maze game? yes|no : \n");
    scanf("%s", &response);
    
    if (!strcmp(response, "yes"))
    {
    printf("\n");
    printf("Game will begin!");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Maze Board Example: \n");
    printf("S##### \n");
    printf(".....# \n");
    printf("#.#### \n");
    printf("#.#### \n");
    printf("...#.G \n");
    printf("##...# \n");
    printf("\n");
        
    printf("Intstructions:");
    printf("Are you ready to play? ready|no \n");
    scanf("%s", &response);
    
    if (!strcmp(response, "ready"))
    {
        printf("playing...");
        

        system("cls");



        while(1)
        {
            mazeGo();
        }
    }
    

    }
    
    
    
    
    
    if (!strcmp(response, "no"))
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Game will exit");

    }
    
    return 0;
    
    
    
    
}

    
    
void mazeGo()
{


    str1[0]= '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[7] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[8] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[9] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[10] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[11] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[15] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[22] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[28] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[29] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[30] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[37] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[38] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[39] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[32] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    str1[33] = '+';
    printf("%s", str1);
    sleep(1);
    system("cls");
    
    printf("\n You win!");
    
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could add the error (messages) you had to your question. On first sight, the `system("cls")` will generally not work on Linux. It is a built-in command of Windows' `CMD.EXE`, which is what runs the "strings" you pass to `system()` on Windows. On Linux it would (for the sake of argument) be a "bourne-shell", so try `system("clear")` instead. YMMV.

Comment: why are there so many unnecessary blank lines?

Comment: Indentation is inconsistent too. Makes it hard to read.

Comment: Unrelated: use a Linux [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) running inside your windows host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot imagine you got no warnings on Windows...

```
...
printf("Do you want to play the maze game? yes|no : \n");
scanf("%s", &response);
...
```

=> format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]

It should be `scanf("%s", response);` or even better: `scanf("%9s", response);`

That is enough to invoke Undefined Behaviour and have the program run smoothly, crash at any moment or provide non consistent output... And the error is repeated in the program...

```
system("cls");
```

=> warning: implicit declaration of function 'system'

Not an error of course, but best practices recommend to *declare* functions before using them. You should use `#include <stdlib>`

```
void mazeGo()
```

=> warning: conflicting types for 'mazeGo'

The identifier was first encountered at `mazeGo();` and was implitely declared as `int mazeGo()`. You should have a `void mazeGo();` declaration before main

And a number or unused variables. Here again it is not an error but leaving unused variables in a code could hide typos and make future maintenance harder.

Apart from that, `system("cls")` will clear the screen only on Windows. On Linux the shell started by `system` will complain for an unknown command but it should not abort the program.

TL/DR:

1. Warnings are not to be ignored
2. If the program had been correct on Windows it would have run on Linux (except for the screen clearing)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should add the return type of void to your main function.

```
void main()...
```

then you're trying to execute the "cls" command, which in linux will not work, because it's a windows specific command.

Comment: The [correct return type for `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/204483#204483) is `int`, independent of the system. (And OP does `return 0` at the end, so the function isn't void.)

Comment: `main() {...` without the return type would at least be interpreted as `int main() {...`. Said differently this suggestion makes the code worse than it already is :-(